# How to restart a service after PackageGroup in the Chain element

Tags: wix, bootstrapper

I'm trying to add TeamViewer to my Chain in the BootStrapper.  One of the request was that I had to install TeamViewer Silently with no UI but with certain features enabled.  After talking to TeamViewer support, they told me to export my registries from my TeamViewer on the target machine, then restart the teamViewer Service.

So I extracted the reg file, use heat to harvest the entries, and created an MSI that pushes the reg values on the target machine.

The next step that I need to do, is restart the teamViewer service.

How do I do that since I'm not installing the service. I looked at RestartResource but didn't find any samples of what I wanted to do, I'll keep searching hoping to find help ...

**EDIT**

I'm currently testing

```
<util:RestartResource Id="rrTeamViewerService" ServiceName="TeamViewer9"/>
```

Rob?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ServiceControl element in your MSI to control a service you haven't installed.

Comment: I was looking at the log files, how do I know that the Service restarted ... didn't see anything that indicated that in there?

Comment: I'd check the event log - what ServiceControl commands are you using?

Comment: I've tried Start=install && Start=both, reading more about ServiceControl it says: This element is used to control the state of a service installed by the MSI or MSM file by using the start, stop and remove attributes.  I'm not installing the service